# How do you separate your application logging from NServiceBus framework logging

Tags: nservicebus4

NServiceBus writes to the logs into the folder where the host process is. How can I write my application specific log to a separate file using log4net so that I look at the application logs and then if there is a NServiceBus issue, I go look at the NServiceBus logs.

If I go the IWantCustomLogging route, everything gets written to the destination file.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Prasad

Answer (score 1):

You can configure that in app.config.  http://particular.net/articles/generic-host-sample